# Clicking the right arrow in my image gallery to go to the next image, does not work

Tags: javascript, html

On my home page, I have an image gallery of 3 small images side by side horizantally. And I have "<" and ">" arrows to the left and right of my gallery of small images. I also have the index of the last small image clicked by the user, saved in localStorage item "index". When the user clicks the right arrow, I want to show the next small image border in black and also display the matching big image from the data array above the small image. In my html code below, I have mysql image gallery rows passed from node.js in **data**  array. But no matter what I try, I can't get it to work. I checked similar questions at this site but found no satisfactory answers. I have changed my js code many times to try different things, the js code below is the last version. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
function nxt_img(data) {
        var last_selectn_index = localStorage.getItem('index');
        if (last_selectn_index) {  //If there is a selection from last time.
            for (var i = last_selectn_index; i < gallery_smlimg.length; i++){
                gallery_smlimg[i].style.border = "none"; //Hide border
                if (i == (gallery_smlimg.length - 1)) {  //If last index,
                    gallery_smlimg[0].style.border = "3px solid black"; //Start over from 1st. 
                    localStorage.setItem('index', 0);  //Save the 1st image index in local storage.
                } else {
                    i++
                    console.log("i: ", i);
                    gallery_smlimg[i].style.border = "3px solid black";
                    gallery_bigimg.src = data[i].gallery_bigimg_locn;
                    localStorage.setItem('index', i);  //Save the image index in local  storage. 
                    i = gallery_smlimg.length;
                }    
            }     
        } else {  //If there is no selection from last time.
            gallery_smlimg[0].style.border = "3px solid black";  //Start over from 1st image
            sessionStorage.setItem('index', 0);  //Save the 1st image index in local storage.
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="gallery_section" >       
        <br>
        <img src="<%=data[0].gallery_bigimg_locn%>" id="gallery_bigimg" class="gallery_bigimg" onclick="pass_selection_to_nodejs()">  
        <div class="gallery_smlimgs" id="gallery_smlimgs" >
            <button class="prev_img_btn" type="button" style="margin-left: 25%;"><</button>
            <% if(data.length){ for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>
                    <img src="<%=data[i].gallery_smlimg_locn%>" class="gallery_smlimg" id="gallery_smlimg" onclick="smlimg_clicked(event, '<%=data[i].gallery_smlimg%>', 
                    '<%=data[i].gallery_bigimg_locn%>', '<%=data[i].gallery_selection_name%>', '<%=data[i].gallery_selection_type%>')">
                <%}  %> 
            <% } %>
            <button class="nxt_img_btn" id="nxt_img_btn" type="button" style="margin-left: 10px;" onclick="nxt_img('<%=data%>')">></button>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.